# ifconfig seemingly disagrees with Centos Network Connections preference

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ifconfig

My Centos VirtualBox currently has no network connection and (as far as I can tell) no IPv4 address.

The GUI Network Connections preference box lists a single configuration, which I manually renamed from "barret" to "eth1" thinking that could solve some problems. The eth1 configuration has an IPv4 address and IPV6s setting on "Ignore". The Connect automatically box is checked. In the list of configurations, under "Last Used", it says "6 days ago." There's no apparent way to instruct it to start using eth1 now.

In terminal, if I run the command ifconfig by itself, [this is the full output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svcKE.png)

Sorry it's a picture, I seem to have lost the shared clipboard feature.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `ifconfig` anymore for multiple reasons (unmaintained, known issues, superseded by superior tools, etc.). I think it's rather likely to be an `ifconfig` issue.

See also:

- [Deprecated Linux networking commands and their replacements](http://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/)
- [iproute2: Life after ifconfig](http://andys.org.uk/bits/2010/02/24/iproute2-life-after-ifconfig/)
- [ifconfig sucks](http://inai.de/2008/02/19)